# 4-cycle decomposition of a complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

Let $K_n$ be the complete graph with n vertices where the number of edges $\frac {n \times (n-1)} {2}$ is a multiple of 4. Can this graph be decomposed into 4-cycles? (i.e find a partition of the set of edges such that each subset of the partition contains a subset of the edges that form a 4-cycle).

I am particularly interested for the case where $n = 9$ but it would be interesting to know if there is any general theorem. Also, what happens in the case when instead of 1 edge between each pair of vertices we have $k$ edges instead?

Comment: I know that, if $K_n$ has a $4$-cycle decomposition, then $n\equiv 1\pmod{8}$.  I believe the converse holds, but I don't know yet how to prove it.

Comment: By "1 edge between each vertex" I guess you mean "1 edge between each pair of vertices"?

Comment: @bof yes that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the case of $K_9$, one such decomposition is drawn below: the cycles are
$$
   \{(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 4, 1, 5), (0, 6, 1, 7), (0, 2, 4, 9), (1, 3, 5, 8), \\(2, 6, 3, 7), (2, 5, 6, 8), (3, 4, 7, 8), (4, 5, 7, 6)\}.
$$
[image: k9]

Based on my comments to the other question, there is a general solution (found by a cooperative effort). For $K_{8k+1}$ we have a decomposition by taking the cycles $(i, i+4j, i+1, i+4j-2)$ for $i=0,1,\dots,8k$ and $j=1, \dots, k$, where all addition is done modulo $8k+1$.

The $n=8k+1$ case is the only case where a decomposition is possible. We need all vertex degrees to be even, since each cycle uses up $2$ edges out of its vertices, which means $n$ has to be odd. At the same time, the number of edges, which is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, must be divisible by $4$, so $n(n-1)$ is divisible by $8$. Since $n$ is odd, this only happens if $n-1$ is divisible by $8$: if $n=8k+1$ for some $k$.

Comment: Nice............

Comment: Awesome! I see in one of the comments that you used Mathematica to generate that, would you mind sharing what commands you used to do it? Can Wolfram Alpha be used as well?

Comment: The idea is to construct a new graph whose vertices are the 4-cycles of $K_9$ and whose edges are conflicts between them, then call `FindIndependentVertexSet` on that graph. This finds a maximum set of non-overlapping cycles, which happens to be a decomposition. (I did a bit of symmetry breaking by assuming that the first cycle is $(0,1,2,3)$ and filtering on that, but that only helps the process go faster.) I don't think Wolfram Alpha can be convinced to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a regular nonagon and note the the edges between vertices come in $4$ different lengths, $9$ of each length. So, if you can find a $4$ cycle that contains edges of all different lengths, then you can rotate that $4$ cycle by ninths of a full turn to get the rest of the cover.

Label the vertices $0$ through $8$ going around the nonagon. Find that $(0,1,5,2)$ meets our criteria. Now rotate by adding 1 to each vertex number mod $9$ to get:

$\{(0,1,5,2),(1,2,6,3),(2,3,7,4),(3,4,8,5),(4,5,0,6),(5,6,1,7),(6,7,2,8),(7,8,3,0),(8,0,4,1)\}$

Comment: Very nice! I was thinking of something like this, but eventually decided to be lazy and brute-force the problem in Mathematica. Your approach can probably be extended to a general solution: if there are vertices numbered $0, 1, \dots, 8k$ around a circle, then there are $4k$ different lengths, each occurring $n=8k+1$ times. So if we can find $k$ cycles that together use each length exactly once, we can generate a full solution by rotating.

Comment: For instance, for $n=17$ we can rotate the two cycles $(0,8,1,6)$ and $(2,3,7,5)$.

Comment: For a general solution with $n=8k+1$: take the cycles $(0, 4i, 1, 4i-2)$ for $i=1, \dots, k$, which gets us the lengths $4i,4i-1,4i-3,4i-2$, and rotate each of them $n$ times.

Comment: Nicely done. I didn't think a general solution would be so simple.